# Emprega-se vírgula antes de 'etc'?

Tags: etimologia, pontuação

Podemos observar que a maioria das pessoas(inclusive escritores e especialistas na língua portuguesa) utilizam vírgula antes de **'etc'**. Ora, se 'etc' etimologicamente é a abreviação de "*et coetera*" e significa: "e outras coisas", "e as coisas restantes", "e o resto". A vírgula não seria desnecessária?

Exemplos:

> Ele gosta de esportes com bola: futebol, vólei, basquete, etc

ou

> Ele gosta de esportes com bola: futebol, vólei, basquete etc

**Devemos ou não utilizar vírgula antes de 'etc'?**

Referência:
ALMEIDA, Nilson Teixeira de. Gramática da Língua Portuguesa. 9 ed. São Paulo: Saraiva, 2009

Comment: Tu não utilizarias vírgula antes do último elemento de uma enumeração? Eu utilizaria... será contágio cultural da língua inglesa?

Comment: Virgula antes da conjunção _e_ em uma enumeração é construção usual em inglês, é conhecida como _Oxford Comma_ e visa eliminar a possibilidade interpretação dos últimos dois elementos da enumeração como aposto do antepenúltimo elemento. Contudo, seu uso não é incontroverso mesmo entre os anglófonos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não encontrei nada que definitivamente obrigue a preceder o *etc.* de vírgula, mas a grande maioria dos escritores e gramáticos é assim que escrevem. Vejam por exemplo [*Pontuação do etc.* do Prof. Cláudio Moreno.](http://sualingua.com.br/2009/05/13/pontuacao-do-etc/) A justificação da vírgula vem de a generalidade dos falantes do português, tal como os de outras línguas, mesmo os que sabem que *etc.* é abreviatura de *et cetera*, entenderem *etc.* com uma palavra só, e o *et* como a primeira sílaba dessa palavra e não como uma palavra autónoma equivalente ao nosso *e*.

Aliás, se nós ficássemos presos à origem da expressão, não poderíamos dizer coisas como, «o Pedro, o João, a Maria, etc.» porque *cetera* significa *outras coisas*, não *outras pessoas*. E há quem defenda isto mesmo, que não se use *etc.* para listas de pessoas. O gramático brasileiro Celso Pedro Luft observou ironicamente que, se quiséssemos ser mesmo fieis à origem da expressão, não a poderíamos usar para nada, porque *cetera* é neutro, e nós só temos substantivos femininos e masculinos. (Seria tão incorreto como dizer, «o João, o Pedro e outras».)

A quem queira omitir a vírgula eu recomendo o seguinte teste de coerência. Escrevo abaixo duas frases deliberadamente sem qualquer pontuação. Como é que as leem?

> (a) Podes trazer o cão o gato o canário e os outros
>
> (b) Podes trazer o cão o gato o canário etc.

Agora vejam como é que entoam as frases, nomeadamente onde é que fazem pausas. Eu vou dizer o que é que eu faço. Em (a) faço pausa só a seguir a *cão* e a *gato*; em (b) faço também a seguir a *canário*. Se não fizesse pausa entre *canário* e *etc.*, pareceria que estava a falar do canário etecétera, isto é, um canário chamado *etcetera*. Como eu não pontuo de acordo com regras arbitrárias, antes indico com pontuação na escrita as pausas da fala, escrevo:

> Podes trazer o cão, o gato, o canário e os outros.
>
> Podes trazer o cão, o gato, o canário, etc.

Portanto eu recomendo que, por coerência, escreva «canário etc.» quem pronuncie *canário et cetera* sem pausas (como pronunciariam *canário e outros*) tomando conscientemente e pronunciando o *et* como equivalente a *e*; e escreva «canário, etc.» quem fizer a pausa entre *canário* e *etc.*

Em trabalhos académicos é comum abreviar listas longas de coautores, como «Alves, Bastos e Costa» para «Alves *et al.*» [*Et al.*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/et_al.) é abreviação do latim *et alii*, que significa e outros. Aqui ninguém escreve vírgula, e coerentemente toda a gente pronuncia «Alves *et al.* sem pausas, tal como pronunciaria «Alves e outros».

Comment: Essa da pausa não me convenceu. Parece-me que em a) há tanto uma pausa a seguir a _o gato_ como antes de _e os outros_.

Comment: @Pois eu não faço pausa, e acho que as pessoas normalmente não fazem. Parece-me até que que *canário e os outros*  é praticamente pronunciado como *canários outros*.

Comment: Com dois elementos não há pausa, com uma enumeração de 3 ou mais, há. Pelo menos é essa a minha sensibilidade. Mas hei de ficar atento.

Answer (score 5):

O termo 'etc' é a abreviação da ideia de continuidade, por exemplo, "e outras coisas". Observe que o conectivo 'e' já está embutido no sentido de 'etc', o que nos isenta de fazer uso do mesmo em uma sentença.

Gramáticos condenam o uso de vírgula devida presença implícita do 'e', no entanto, ela tornou-se facultativa, pois o termo 'etc', com o tempo, passou a representar um termo enumerativo.